# $\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}[\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1+X_{n,i}}{2}] = 1 \implies \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}\left[\prod_{i=1}^n X_{n,i} \right] = 1$

Tags: probability, limits, random-variables

Suppose I have a sequence of random variables $X_{n,i}$ with $i=1,...,n$. Each of these random variables is strictly bounded between $-1$ and $1$. I know that each of these random variables is getting closer and closer to $1$ as $n$ grows.

Specifically, I know that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}[\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1+X_{n,i}}{2}] = 1$$

In fact, I know that for every sequence of subsets $A_n$ of $\{1,...,n\}$, I have

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}[\prod_{i\in A_n} \frac{1+X_{n,i}}{2}] = 1$$

I also know that for any such subset $A_n$, the random variables are positively correlated in the sense that

$$\mathbb{E}[\prod_{i\in A_n} X_{n,i}] \geq \prod_{i\in A_n}\mathbb{E}[ X_{n,i}]$$

These constraints give me some nice knowledge. For example, if I consider the subset $A_n = \{1 \}$, I can see that $\frac{1+\lim_{n\to \infty} \mathbb{E}[X_{n,1}]}{2} =1$, so that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \mathbb{E}[X_{n,1}] =1$. More generally, I can see that for any positive integer $m$, $\lim_{n\to \infty} \mathbb{E}[X_{n,m}] =1$. Even more generally, I can see that quantities like $\lim_{n\to \infty} \mathbb{E}[X_{n,1}...X_{n,10}] =1$.

However, am I guaranteed that
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \mathbb{E}[ \prod_{i=1}^n X_{n,i}] = 1?$$

---

If the random variables are independent, the answer is yes. We can see this from the following argument.

For independent random variables, we know that $\mathbb{E}[\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1+X_{n,i}}{2}] = \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1+\mathbb{E}[X_{n,i}]}{2}$ and $\mathbb{E}[ \prod_{i=1}^n X_{n,i}] = \prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}[  X_{n,i}]$.

It will be useful to write $y_{n,i} = \frac{1}{2}(1-\mathbb{E}[X_{n,i}])$, and note that $y_{n,i}$ is bounded between $0$ and $\frac{1}{2}$.

Then

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}[\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1+X_{n,i}}{2}] = 1 \implies \lim_{n \to \infty} \prod_{i=1}^n (1-y_{n,i}) = 1$$

Note that the bounds on $y_{n,i}$ mean that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \prod_{i=1}^n (1-y_{n,i}) = 1$ implies that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \max_i y_{n,i} = 0$.

Note that $\mathbb{E}[ \prod_{i=1}^n X_{n,i}] = \prod_{i=1}^n (1-2 y_{n,i})$.

We can use that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \max_i y_{n,i} = 0$ to note that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \prod_{i=1}^n (1-2 y_{n,i}) \geq \lim_{n \to \infty}  \prod_{i=1}^n (1- y_{n,i})^3$$
so that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \prod_{i=1}^n (1-2 y_{n,i}) \geq 1$. Since $\lim_{n \to \infty} \prod_{i=1}^n (1-2 y_{n,i}) \leq 1$ trivially, we have $\lim_{n \to \infty} \prod_{i=1}^n (1-2 y_{n,i}) = 1$.

---

The proof was straightforward for this case of independent variables, but I don't quite see an extension to more general positively correlated variables. By positively correlated, I mean in the sense above of $\mathbb{E}[\prod_{i\in A_n} X_{n,i}] \geq \prod_{i\in A_n}\mathbb{E}[ X_{n,i}]$. My hope is that a similar proof can go through, but I'll also accept counterexamples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that my argument above with $1-y$ versus $1-2y$ actually largely goes through with minor modifications, and I do not need to assume any positive correlations.

Instead of $y_{n,i} = \frac{1}{2}(1-\mathbb{E}[X_{n,i}])$, I'll define $Y_{n,i} = \frac{1}{2}(1-X_{n,i})$. Note that $Y_{n,i}$ is between $0$ and $1$.

We have $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}[\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1+X_{n,i}}{2}] = 1 \implies \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}[\prod_{i=1}^n (1-Y_{n,i})] = 1$$

and we have

$$\mathbb{E}[ \prod_{i=1}^n X_{n,i}] = \mathbb{E}[\prod_{i=1}^n (1-2 Y_{n,i})]$$

Note that with high probability we can say $(1-2 Y_{n,i})$ > $(1- Y_{n,i})^3$; for example, if we introduce an indicator function $\mathbb{1}_{\forall i, Y_{n,i} < .1}$, we have

$$\begin{split}\mathbb{E}[\prod_{i=1}^n (1-2 Y_{n,i})] &= \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_{\forall i, Y_{n,i} < .1} \prod_{i=1}^n (1-2 Y_{n,i})] + \mathbb{E}[(1-\mathbb{1}_{\forall i, Y_{n,i} < .1}) \prod_{i=1}^n (1-2 Y_{n,i})] \\ &\geq \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_{\forall i, Y_{n,i} < .1} \prod_{i=1}^n (1-2 Y_{n,i})] 
\\&\geq \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_{\forall i, Y_{n,i} < .1} \prod_{i=1}^n (1- Y_{n,i})^3]
\\ &\to  \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_{\forall i, Y_{n,i} < .1}]
\\ &\to 1 \end{split}$$